# How to load components from Module A into a template in Module B the angular way?

Tags: angular

We have a panel component that is placed in the `MainModule`. This panel is controlled by a `PanelService`. From other modules we can now load a form into the panel to edit a user for example like this: `panelService.openPanel(new EditUserForm(userToEdit))`. This form class is just the representation of the form, not the actual form component. In this case the form component would be the `EditUserFormComponent`. For the panel component to know which concrete component to load, we register all panel components in the modules where they belong like this: `panelUiService.registerContent('EditUserForm', EditUserFormComponent)`.

It works, but as this is such a common problem to solve my question is: What would be the "Angular way" to do this?

We have distinct layers in our application, so it would not fit into our architecture to deal with concrete components in the application layer where a use case is started to edit a user. But I assume this is common practice anyways.

Of course we also don't want the `PanelComponent` or `PanelService` to have knowledge about what kind of components are part of other modules.

Comment: Do you mean something like portals from the CDK ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. To open a portal you have to pass a component to the open method. So in a layered architecture this belongs to the UI layer, while the workflow (edit the current user) is started in the application layer.